# ¿Cómo hacer LEFT JOIN con subconsulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo este query donde nececito hacer algo similar a esto pero mi pregunta es como hago la
referencia a tablas fuera en la consulta del left join en el where para que solo lo haga en el codigo
de ese registro me da "error hal hacer la referencia o no se puede enlazar" estoy utilizando sql server

```
select
   a.id,
   a.producto,
   b.total
   from productos a
   left join 
   (
       select
           producto,
           sum(total)
       from
          vendido
       where
          producto = c.id
       group by producto 
   )b
   on a.id = b.producto
   left join fac c
      on fac.producto = a.id
```

Comment: Agrega el nombre de la columna `sum(total) as total`

Comment: si pero ese no es el problema principal el problema esta al enlazar from
          vendido
       where
          producto = c.id
       group by producto

Comment: ya que no se puede enlazar a la consulta externa o como lo haria

Comment: No no puedes, la subconsulta deberías hacerla sin el  `where  producto = c.id`.

Comment: tal vez, si nos explicas porque tu lolgica implica tratar de enlazar algo que logicamente no esta en ese momento en la consulta, podriamos ayudarte a resolverlo...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, no puedes referenciar una tabla en el `FROM` antes de incluirla. En segundo lugar, para hacer referencias a tablas externas en una subconsulta en el `FROM`, tienes que usar `APPLY`. Por último, es una buena práctica el utilizar alias relevantes y que no dependan del orden en que aparecen las tablas en el `FROM`.

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   p.producto,
   pv.total
FROM productos p
LEFT JOIN fac f ON f.producto = p.id
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT v.producto,
                    SUM(v.total) AS total
               FROM vendido v
               WHERE v.producto = c.id
               AND   v.producto = p.id
               GROUP BY v.producto ) pv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes de tener es un escenario, claro, porque la consulta, aunque te parezca obvia, tiene o puede tener sus "cositas", y quizá se te puedan escapar.

Como de la consulta se supone que enlazas con `fac` para algo que no muestras, pues vamos a pensar que necesitas alguna columna y es más, dado que usas `left Join`, habrá que suponer que quieres ***productos*** que pueden tener o no su ***factura***.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS
             (
             ID       INT
           , PRODUCTO CHAR(1)
             );

CREATE TABLE VENDIDO
             (
             ID       INT
           , PRODUCTO INT
           , TOTAL    INT
             );

CREATE TABLE FAC
             (
             ID       INT
           , PRODUCTO INT
           , CLIENTE  INT
             );
```

Lo único diferente a lo que has mostrado, es la inclusión de una columna `Cliente` en la tabla `fac`.

Ahora insertamos 3 registros en `productos`. Y 2 en `fac` y `ventas`. Pero con su trampa, porque hay uno que tiene fac y no venta, y uno que tiene venta y no fac.

Esto que a priori, suena raro, es importante cuando haces una pregunta, porque a lo mejor en la base de datos que trabajas no es posible, o si, y en función de que lo sea, la respuesta, puede ser una u otra diferente.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (ID, PRODUCTO)
VALUES
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C');
INSERT INTO VENDIDO (ID, PRODUCTO, TOTAL)
VALUES
(1,1,10),
(2,1,20),
(3,1,10),
(4,2,10);
INSERT INTO FAC(ID, PRODUCTO, CLIENTE)
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,3,2);
```

Te comento esto, porque cuando haces un enlace de tabla interior a exterior, tienes que tener en cuenta con quién enlaza. Si solo con `productos` o tambien con `fac`.

**OPERADOR APPLY**

Funciona igual que un left join, pero relacionando el registro de la tabla interior con la tabla exterior.

```
Select
      prod.ID
    , prod.PRODUCTO
    , FAC.CLIENTE
    , ventas.Total
   from productos as prod
   left join fac on prod.ID = fac.PRODUCTO
   outer apply
   (
       select
           producto,
           sum(total) as Total
       from
          vendido
       where
          vendido.producto = prod.id
       group by producto 
   ) as ventas
```

[image: Res1]

El producto B, tiene ventas, pero no fac y como no lo enlazamos con fac pues sale igual. Si lo enlazas con `fac`, tendrás un null para esa fila

Ten en cuenta, que ventas retornará un valor para cada fila exterior haya o no datos.

**OPCIÓN CTE**

Pero esa no es más que una de las muchas maneras de solicitar esa información.

```
With cte as (
   select
           producto,
           sum(total) as Total
       from
          vendido
       group by producto 
)
Select
      prod.ID
    , prod.PRODUCTO
    , FAC.CLIENTE
    , ventas.Total
   from productos as prod
   left join fac on prod.ID = fac.PRODUCTO
   left join cte as ventas on prod.ID = ventas.PRODUCTO;
```

Si en una cte, haces la suma agrupada por producto, y en la salida de la cte, haces la query y la relacionas con el conjunto cte, obtienes el mismo resultado.

[image: Res2]

Ahora bien, si enlazas con `fac` y tienes más de un registro por **producto**, obtendrás lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO FAC(ID, PRODUCTO, CLIENTE)
VALUES
(3,1,2);
```

Independiente de la opción utilizada o incluso de si muestras o no columnas de `fac`.

```
Select
      prod.ID
    , prod.PRODUCTO
    --, FAC.CLIENTE
    , ventas.Total
   from productos as prod
   left join fac on prod.ID = fac.PRODUCTO
   outer apply
   (
       select
           producto,
           sum(total) as Total
       from
          vendido
       where
          vendido.producto = prod.id
       group by producto 
   ) as ventas
```

[image: Res3]

[Operador Apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

[Cte](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)